# Ebean is not creating dbfile, how do i get it to work?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

i have a class User which extends Ebean Model. And i defined a dbfile in my application.conf and by starting h2, it is creating the dbfile. my quesion is:

do i have to create my User Table manually in H2 Console in DB? or does Ebean create it automatically. if Ebean does, how and where i will see User Table in DB? i am confused a little bit..

thanks for clarification in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Evolutions).

So you must create a SQL file under `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql` (assuming that in application.conf your database is under "default"). This file must contain your `CREATE TABLE` statements, and it will be executed on Play startup.

Comment: ebean will create this statements automatically?

Comment: okay, i see, ebean is creating the file itself once i run the app. now i have another question of how to save the values got from post into Model fields.. :D. Nico, any ideas? :))